# can i avoid to show home page slider for individual event by joomla event module?

Tags: events, joomla

i've uploaded a joomla (version 1.5.26) site: http://srajib.info/s2l/

when i click any particular event (Right side), it also shows home slider:
http://srajib.info/s2l/index.php?option=com_jevents&task=icalrepeat.detail&evid=3&Itemid=1&year=2013&month=09&day=07&title=long-jump-event&uid=07390f799fedccea98b8ed46532fa4cb&catids=1

if i click any date of calendar (Right side), it also shows home page slider.

how can i avoid to show home slider both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to your **Module Manager**
- Identify your **frontpage slider module**, and click on its name
- In the **Menu assigments** section click the **Select Menu Item(s) from the List** option
- From the list below it you can select the pages/menu items that you wish the module to be displayed on. Make sure to deselect the **Events** and **Calendar** menu items.
- Click the **Save** icon in the top toolbar.